# Getting 404 Not Found/ File Not Found When a specific URL is hit but in browser it does give the result

Tags: java, httprequest, httpurlconnection, httpresponse

I know this may be a duplicate question but I applied all the patches as suggested in other related questions, but still have no luck resolving the issue.

The issue is When I hit a URL (It's an API provided by SMS provider through which we send SMS to our clients. It worked for more than a year and suddenly we start getting an exception.)  from Browser I get the required result but When I do it through code then it gives me 404 Not Found. It freaks me out when 1 out (10/20) hit is successful and I get a response to that specific hit.

URL we hit:

```
  https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/xml
```

In response, we git XML based text file. e.g if I hit the above URL from a browser I get a file with a name api.txt which has an XML based response.

This is the code I have written.

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

This is the exception:

```
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/xml?api_key=apiKey&api_secret=password&from=ourprojectname&to=mobilenumber&account-ref=account_registeration_number&text=encoded_message&type=text
```

As the provider accepts requests as post also.We converted this code for sending post request still getting the same exception.

As this URL is when hitting through a browser we are getting a response so I added a header user-agent in request property still got the same exception.

we have some certificate problem for other URLs before which we fixed. Added the same configuration for this URL still getting the same 404 response.

**Need some suggestion on this matter any small help will be appreciated.**

Comment: You are actually sending "account-ref=account_registeration_number"? If it's a restful api, it may well say 404 because it can't find the account-ref "account_registeration_number".

Comment: @Christine Yeah we are sending it. The whole thing is it failed suddenly. Otherwise, it was working for what you have told. And another thing it does find it if I hit same URL in browser.

Comment: Is it your api, or a public api? If it's yours, you'll have to take a look at the log files. Also, you can try with restclient or soapui, which give you more feedback than your browser.

Comment: It is public API. We resolved it. That told us that they haven't  done any changes but actually, they did. They accept only those request which has their custom user-agent in the request header. Somehow found that user-agent value and We were good. Thank you @Christine for looking into the problem.